# How to connect to postgress via docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I have a fastapi application that connects to a postgress via the url:

DB_URL = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:0000@localhost:5432/store

I tried to run my application in a docker container using:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: app-img
    container_name: app-ctr
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - database
    
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-ctr
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 0000
      POSTGRES_DB: store
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

This is the command my application used to start the application inside the container:

```
Dockerfile
...
CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

How can I fix this connection error?

Answer (score 0):

In the database URL you have to replace localhost by postgres-ctr, which is the host name of your postgres database container specified in your docker compose file. Your webserver will directly connect to the Postgres container through a docker network.

Comment: I follow what you did, but now I am getting another error:

psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at \"db\" (172.24.0.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user.

This is the same excat password I used to connect to server via pgamin

Comment: Does `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "0000"` work?

Comment: @MichaelXia what is "db" here exactly ?